# Generate ejected expo app through eas build

Tags: react-native, expo, build.gradle, apk, eas

I created an expo app then i needed to add a printing package and i could not find any that was supported by expo(if there is any please just comment below) so i ejected my app and i added the `react-native-thermal-printer` package and i want to generate my app apk through `eas build`.Is there any special configurations i have to set for the non expo supported package or do i generete the apk as normal...I have already set up my `eas.json`.Also do i include the generated android folder while uploading to eas ?
Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same question. I wanted to use the EAS build with a non Expo friendly package. According to the documentation, the eas.json should look a little different on bare project, but it does not offer any example. According to the same documentation, there are no additional steps needed for bare projects, it should work with the same configuration as in managed projects.

You can find the official Expo documentation with this not here: [Build configuration process: 2 Create eas.json](https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/build-configuration/#create-easjson)

PS: I did not find time to test it yet, but it is definitely a starting point. I hope it helps!